# WebView android JSOUP

Tags: java, android, webview

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос по поводу парсинга страницы. Через `WebView` я авторизуюсь на сайте, далее при парсинге url-a document будет забираться из `WebView` или как новая страница и без авторизации. И возможно ли вообще организовывать парсинг из `WebView`. Спасибо.